# Flexbox overflow - top of the element is missing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="imgview_overlay" id="imageviewer">
    <div class="overlay_content">
        <div class="overlay_inner" id="overlay_img_div">
            <img id="overlay_img" alt="overlayed_image" style="visibility: hidden;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.imgview_overlay { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2); visibility: hidden; z-index: 500; }
.overlay_content { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
.overlay_inner { display: inline-block; }
```

to horizontally and vertically center the `<img>` tag inside the overlay.

The `overflow: auto;` does its job, but not correctly. The top of the image (when the page is shrinked down) does not appear. As an example, check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ftqgf1u4/) fiddle. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the expected behavior of `justify-content: center; align-items: center`: they force flex items to be centered. And since you can't scroll to negative values, the upper-left overflowing parts will remain hidden.

Instead, I recommend centering with [`auto` margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins). The there is no available space, they won't force the centering.

```css
.imgview_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 500;
}
.overlay_content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.overlay_inner {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgview_overlay" id="imageviewer">
  <div class="overlay_content">
    <div class="overlay_inner" id="overlay_img_div">
      <img id="overlay_img" alt="overlayed_image" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This really saved me from scratching my head for hours.